# Программное изменение цветовой схемы

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-style

возможно ли подменить файл `values/colors.xml`, или `values/styles.xml`?

Суть в следующем: хочу реализовать возможность переключения цветов всего приложения(полная кастомизация), но прописывать к каждой View по id отдельные параметры не выглядит изящным решением. Буду благодарен за любого рода подсказку!

Comment: Насколько я помню, такое реализовано в Телеграмме, попробуйте посмотреть их исходники https://github.com/TelegramOrg/Telegram-Android